# Components aren't being injected into my ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm just trying to setup a boilerplate for angular 1.5.9 with UI Router 1.0.0. I can display my parent state component within the ui-view, however when I nest states within my parent, my components aren't being injected into my ui-view.

This is my index.html

```
<body ng-app="app">
 <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

This is the main component

```
<div class="main-container">
  <banner></banner>
  <div ui-view='ui-view></div>
</div>
```

It is at this point where in I'm unable to inject anything into the ui-view.

This is my javascript file

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: '/',
      component: 'main'
    })
    .state('app.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'ui-view': {
          templateUrl: './app/login/login.html'
        }
      }
    });
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help/direction to the right path would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Additional Info that might be helpful

1. When I reference login as a parent state everything works as expected.
2. The login component is part of a separate module that I've included in my main module.

Comment: If you want to load `login.html` in the `index` page `ui-view` container, you do not need to declare `<div ui-view='ui-view></div>` again in the `main component` file. Are you on alpha.3 version for the ui router ?

Comment: 1.0.0-beta.1, is the version I'm on. I got rid of the named view, however I still am getting a blank page with an empty ui-view when I inspect element

Answer (score 0):

For nesting one child state in each parent component, there is no need to use named views as you did by adding a value of "ui-view" for the `ui-view` directive used in your main component template. Those named views are only required when you want to address more than one ui-view. Then you need to reference them by name.

In your sample, you will not see any content because you also don't target the named view correctly. There are some rules on how to address those named views if the named views are defined in a template which is not the root file. In that case you need to be more specific by referencing the ui-view with a "ui-view-name@state" syntax which would mean "ui-view@app" in your case.

But as already mentioned: In your simple case, just leave out the name for the ui-view and replace the `views` section in your state config with a plain template (or a component reference).

```
.state('app.login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: './app/login/login.html'
});
```

For details on nesting views, please have a look at the great sample apps in the [ui-router docs](https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/hellogalaxy#views).

Comment: Hey, I changed my code to get rid of the named view. I still only get a blank page when I go over to /login. When I inspect element, the ui-view is empty. Do let me know if there's any other helpful that I need to provide.

Comment: Have a look at the console log for errors. Are there any? It also depends if your login is an angular component or if you reference it by specifying just a template and a controller. With your last answer, it seems that login is a component which then cannot be used via templateUrl directly. That's for the non-component, legacy style. So omitting the ui-view name and referencing the login as a component did the trick?

Answer (score 0):

So this one is really strange, I've no explanation as to why it worked the way it did. All I did was change the javascript file to the one below

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      component: 'main'
    })
    .state('login.default', {
      url: '/default',
      component: 'login'
    });
```

Instead of my parent having '/', changed it to '/login'. I'd be keen to know if someone knows the reason behind this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: path/to/main_component.html
    })
    .state('app.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'ui-view': {
          templateUrl: './app/login/login.html'
        }
      }
    });
```

When you are in `app.login` view(state) `ui-view` will be checked in its parent states template. If you don't have a template, it doesn't know where to render.

`'ui-view':{}` is targetted to its parent view.
`'ui-view@':{}` is targetted to the root component that is index.html